# OledbConnection, missing read on 600 more than row on server

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I'm reading data from Excel through OledbConnection. Here data are reading on my **local** perfectly but it is missing to read if 600 more than on **server**.

for exmample:

I have in excel 1603 rows. It just read 636 row on server.

My connection string:

```
<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
```

My controller codes:

```
string filePath = string.Empty;
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}

filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

string conString = string.Empty;
switch (extension)
{
    case ".xls": //For Excel 97-03.  
        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
        break;
    case ".xlsx": //For Excel 07 and above.  
        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
        break;
}

try
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

    using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
            {
                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                //Get the name of First Sheet.  
                connExcel.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                connExcel.Close();

                //Read Data from First Sheet.  
                connExcel.Open();
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                connExcel.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are there any empty rows in the excel?  Normally when this happen with excel a row was removed or you have a empty row in excel.  The excel worksheet has a "Used Area". So when you use "Select *" you are only is getting the used area.

Comment: No empty lines in Excel.  I don't understand. why It's worked on my local but It doesn't work server.

Comment: Same file?  Same version of ACE?

Comment: Yes same file and same version 12.0. I tried another server but same result.

Comment: Is version of Excel on machine the same?  The dll is located in folder like this : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\system\ado\msado15.dll

Comment: Both exactly the same. Reading when less than 600 also on the server.

Comment: So what!!!  There are invisible features on the excel worksheet which you cannot see and using a different version of the ADO dll will give different results.

Comment: I solved the problem. 

`<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES';IMEX=1" />` I added IMEX=1 It worked

Comment: I missed that.  I should of suggested that yesterday.